# nftables - check if key exists in map

Tags: linux, nftables

I am trying to add a rule using a statement that checks if a key exists in map

Assuming the following:

```
add table bridge my_table
add map bridge my_table ip_map { type ipv4_addr : ipv4_addr; }
add element bridge my_table ip_map { 192.168.0.1 : 192.168.1.1 }
add chain bridge my_table my_chain { type filter hook forward priority 0 ; }
```

Now I would like to add rule that checks if the destination ip address of packets is a key of an element in the map. I have tried many different statements, but none worked, e.g.

```
add rule bridge my_table my_chain ip daddr @ip_map counter
add rule bridge my_table my_chain ip daddr map @ip_map counter
add rule bridge my_table my_chain ip daddr exists map @ip_map counter
add rule bridge my_table my_chain ip daddr map @ip_map exists counter
```

With sets the following rule can be used to check if an element is part of a set. However, I need the map lookup in other rules and cannot just use a set.

```
add set bridge my_table ip_set { type ipv4_addr; }
add element bridge my_table ip_set { 192.168.0.1 }
add rule bridge my_table my_chain ip daddr @ip_set counter
```

Of course, I could use a set with the keys of the map as elements in parallel to the map itself, but there has to be a way to check if a key in a map exists.

Comment: coming soon: https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netfilter-devel/patch/20230512121947.26996-1-fw@strlen.de/